# How to copy an Access file to another computer fully?

Tags: ms-access-2010, ms-access-2003

My Access file is made by MS Access 2010 but with .mdb (compatible with Access 2003). When I copy the Access file to another computer which is installed Access 2003, all macros lost. Command button or controls made by VBA remains, but those simple macros like openform, openreport, etc all gone.

Anyone has this problem before?

Comment: did you try to `Save Database As` and select the right format ?

Comment: That would be Save & Publish. Why have macros if you use VBA? Convert all macros to VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by writing all macro under VBA...

I don't understand why there is such problem occurring with simple macros. Yes, I did try to convert all macros into VBA before, but because some macros got conflicts, they don't automatically convert to VBA (conflict with other event written by VBA).

So I have to write all macros in VBA.

Painful.